# Dificuldades em buscar valores num array

Tags: php, array

O seguinte código é um código de incrementação num array.

No entanto, não tenho conseguido selecionar qualquer valor do array. Se der `print_r` nele, ele mostra todos mas se eu tentar aceder com `$guarda_array[1]` ele devolve `Array` e não o nome que pretendo. Algum trecho do código está mal?

```
$guarda_array = array();
$count_pub=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT nome FROM publicidades_sponsors");
$count_tudo=mysqli_num_rows($count_pub);
while($gu=mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_pub)){
    array_push($guarda_array, $gu);
}
```

O `print_r` mostra o seguinte

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [nome] => DIDAXIS1.png ) [1] => Array ( [nome] => DIDAXIS2.png ) [2] => Array ( [nome] => DIDAXIS3.png ) [3] => Array ( [nome] => DIDAXIS4.png ) )
```

Comment: como que fica quando vc da print_r?

Comment: Mostra os valores todos do array

Comment: Certo, mas como é esse resultado?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [nome] => DIDAXIS1.png ) [1] => Array ( [nome] => DIDAXIS2.png ) [2] => Array ( [nome] => DIDAXIS3.png ) [3] => Array ( [nome] => DIDAXIS4.png ) )

Comment: Não é `array_push($guarda_array, $gu["nome"])` que você queria fazer?

Comment: @Pagotti Exatamente! Publique como resposta que darei como aceite quando puder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a intenção é ter como resultado um `array` com o campo "nome" do `SELECT`, você precisa fazer:

```
$guarda_array = array();
$count_pub=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT nome FROM publicidades_sponsors");
$count_tudo=mysqli_num_rows($count_pub);
while($gu=mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_pub)){
    array_push($guarda_array, $gu["nome"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A estrutura do seu array está assim:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [nome] => DIDAXIS1.png 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [nome] => DIDAXIS2.png 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [nome] => DIDAXIS3.png 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [nome] => DIDAXIS4.png 
    ) 
)
```

Então perceba que a sua tentativa erra:

```
$guarda_array[1]
```

Esse `$guarda_array[1]` tem como conteúdo um array, por isso ele retornava `array`, para pegar o `nome` dentro de `$guarda_array[1]`:

```
$guarda_array[1]['nome']
```